# LINQ to Entities can't compile a store expression

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I use Entity Framework 6.0.1 and I have next problem:

I have the next db structure:

```
public class User 
{
   int Id { get; set;}
   string E-mail {get; set;}
   string Name {get; set;}
   ...
}

class House 
{
   string Id {get; set;}
   string Name { get; set; }
   string Street { get; set; }
   . . . 
   IQueryable<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Every House may be linked to many Users. Any User may be linked to many Houses.

I need to create a query in which to get a list of houses to which is attached a particular user
I know only user Id.

I wrote the next statement:

```
var houses = this.context.Houses
                .Where(house => house.Users.Any(i => i.Id == my_searched_user_id));
```

but I get error: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ElementAtOrDefault[String](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String], Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

I change it to

```
var houses = this.context.Houses
                .Where(house => house.Users.**ToList()**.Any(i => i.Id == my_searched_user_id));
```

but without any luck :(

Comment: There is nothing about `ElementAtOrDefault` in the code you've posted. How are you using `houses` variable later on? It's important, because LINQ execution is deferred, so the code you've shown does not actually perform any DB queries, it just creates a query definition, which might be altered with further method calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You added ToList in wrong place. Try next code:

```
     var houses = this.context.Houses
            .Where(house => house.Users.Any(i => i.Id == my_searched_user_id))
            .ToList();
```

ToList will cast IQueryable to IEnumerable, so the query will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

You should not define your Users collection as an IQueryable.  It should instead be an ICollection:

```
public virtual ICollection<User> Users {get;set}
```

I'm surprised that even compiles... but still, that's not really your problem.  Your problem is in code you have not shown.  You need to show all the code because something else is causing this error, something to do with indexing a string variable.